# What is a word (verb) for asking a question where you know the answer, and you're trying to get someone else to say it?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> "And Columbus sailed the ocean blue in...?" the teacher _____ed, scanning the room for someone to call on."

Comment: Not necessarily specific to knowing the answer, but ***prompted*** would fit well here. ***Coaxed*** is another viable alternative.

Comment: The teacher *quizzed* the students?

Comment: @JohnClifford 's suggestion of prompted is very good, and you may also want to look at synonyms, as they would also fit quite nicely.

Comment: The word teachers use for getting students to provide the answer is 'elicit', but that doesn't fit the example sentence though it does answer the question in the title.

Comment: The teacher "questionned/interrogated" the pupils/students.

Comment: @JohnClifford It might be just me, but I can honestly say that my choice to answer with the word I suggested (and not with our good suggestion) was based solely on me thinking that your "prompt" comment entitles you to claim it and that you’d eventually give it as an answer.  Again just me, but I’d say go for it!

Comment: I think the teacher *paused*.

Comment: How about [*Steined*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhiCFdWeQfA)?

Comment: @PapaPoule Posted as an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

**"angling or fishing for the right answer"** seems to fit.

"And Columbus sailed the ocean blue in...?" the teacher scanned the room **fishing/angling** for the right answer."

> - fish for - "To seek something in a sly or indirect way: fish for compliments." - 
>     [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fish)
> - angle for - "to try to get or achieve something in an indirect way" [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/angle+for)

Comment: Also, *baited*.

Answer (score 1):

> The teacher **asked a leading question** : "And Columbus sailed the ocean blue in...?", scanning the room for someone to call on."

**leading question**

> noun. a question phrased in a manner that tends to suggest the desired answer, such as *What do you think of the horrible effects of pollution?* –
>   [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leading+question)

Answer (score 1):

Elicited

> **e·lic·it** / iˈlisit/ 
> **v.** (**-it·ed** , **-it·ing** ) [tr.] evoke or draw out (a response, answer, or fact) from someone in
>   reaction to one's own actions or questions: *they invariably elicit
>   exclamations of approval from guests.* (from *The Oxford Pocket
>   Dictionary of Current English,*  online at
>   [encyclopedia.com](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-elicit.html))

Comment: Couldn't you have sent me a private message instead of vandalizing my comment? I was trying to help, I won't learn rules for that. My God.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be popular from my comment, I'll submit as an answer [***prompted***](http://to%20%E2%80%8Bhelp%20someone,%20%E2%80%8Bespecially%20an%20%E2%80%8Bactor,%20to%20%E2%80%8Bremember%20what%20they%20were%20going%20to%20say%20or%20do:).

> to ​help someone, ​especially an ​actor, to ​remember what they were going to say or do
>
> *Cambridge Dictionary*

Although the definition does say "especially an actor" there's no reason you can't use this for a teacher who's trying to nudge students towards an answer. Alternatively, you have [***coaxed***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coax).

> to ​persuade someone ​gently to do something or go ​somewhere, by being ​kind and ​patient, or by ​appearing to be
>
> *Cambridge Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***spoon-feed***

> : to give someone information in a way that requires or allows no further thinking or effort
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoon%E2%80%93feed)

Alternately, ***hand [the answer] to [them] on a silver platter*** might fit he bill.

> hand to on a silver platter
>
> *Also*,**serve up on a plate**. Provide with something valuable for nothing, or give an unearned reward to; **also, make it easy for** (emphasis is mine.) For example, *She did no work at all, expecting to have everything handed to her on a silver platter*, or *Just ask them—they'll serve up the data on a plate*. Both terms allude to being elaborately served at the table. [ Early 1900s ]
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hand-to-on-a-silver-platter)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, I'd suggest **hinted** where the association with the rhyme

> Columbus sailed the blue
>
> In 1492

is the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from @k1eran ‘s good “[asked a] leading question,” attorneys/police officers should avoid asking questions or behaving  in such a way that might “[**cue**](https://books.google.com/books?id=sSzxXQmkvrIC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%22cue+the+witness%22+leading+question&source=bl&ots=o9XSSGKOsk&sig=8IlOf2xVoWtvNhIST1VYagz-nDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuq4-o3-PLAhUFGB4KHfS_C7cQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22cue%20the%20witness%22%20%22leading%20questions%22&f=false)” witnesses to give desired responses, although in your classroom example it would be perfectly acceptable:

> “…  the teacher [cued {the
>   students}](https://books.google.com/books?id=OAcVEOEcRx4C&pg=PA47&dq=%22cue+the+students+by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59ZDf5uPLAhVGGh4KHcn1DLgQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22cue%20the%20students%20by%22&f=false),
>   scanning the room for someone to call on."

(police example from ‘Psychology and Policing’ by Peter Ainsworth and classroom example from ‘Successful Movement Challenges: Movement Activities for the Developing Child’ by Jack Capon, both via ‘Google Books’)

> [**cue**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cue)
>      cued …
>   transitive verb
>     1 :  to give a cue to :  prompt
>
> **cue**   [noun]
>     1 a :  a signal (as a word, phrase, or bit of stage
>   business) to a performer to begin a specific speech or action
>      b : 
>   something serving a comparable purpose :  hint

(from ‘Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score -2):

I like variations of **to dig**:

*To bring to light or out of hiding*, as in facts; transitive verb [Webster's]

In your example:

*After no one replied, the teacher further dug for the answer. "The year rhymes with blue? ... It starts with 'Fourteen'?"*

It just occurred to me that **hinted** might be the ticket.

Comment: Wow, really? How about *hinted*?